# IndexError indexing a 2D array with a 1D array (NumPy)

Tags: python, numpy, one-hot-encoding

I have a NumPy array of labels:

```
labels = np.ndarray(10000, dtype=np.float32)
```

The elements in array look like:

```
print(labels[1:5])
Output: [ 9.  9.  4.  1.]
```

I want to convert them into one hot encoded labels and I have used the following code:

```
one_hot_labels = np.eye(10)[labels]
```

I get the following error:

```
IndexError     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-dccf85afc031> in <module>()
  1 
----> 2 s=np.eye(10)[labels]

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure labels and train labels are the same?

Comment: You need to use integer values as indices:  `one_hot_labels=np.eye(10)[labels.astype(int)]`

Comment: @JohanL Thanks. It works

Answer (score 3):

You have defined your labels as `np.float32`. If they are to be used as indices into an array or matrix they must be integers. To convert a `np.float32` use `.astype(int)`:

```
 one_hot_labels=np.eye(10)[labels.astype(int)]
```

or define the labels as ints directly:

```
labels=np.ndarray(10000,dtype=int)
```

Comment: @Jayanth If he answered your question, please accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If `labels` is `float` and you don't wish to change its `dtype`, you could simply use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer). This snippet should get the job done:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
one_hot_labels = mlb.fit_transform(labels[:, None])
```